# PyAsn1 error when reading a PEM string

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa, python-3.4, pem

I'm trying to read a PEM encoded public-key in Python. I've tried multiple keys and multiple possible solutions. I tried base64 decoding it, other formats, ect...

I really don't know what to do anymore (since I'm already having this problem since yesterday).

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:/path/Main.py", line 6, in <module>
    -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----""", format='PEM')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rsa-3.1.4-py3.4.egg\rsa\key.py", line 65, in load_pkcs1
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rsa-3.1.4-py3.4.egg\rsa\key.py", line 192, in _load_pkcs1_pem
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rsa-3.1.4-py3.4.egg\rsa\key.py", line 160, in _load_pkcs1_der
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyasn1-0.1.7-py3.4.egg\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 792, in __call__
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyasn1-0.1.7-py3.4.egg\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 321, in valueDecoder
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyasn1-0.1.7-py3.4.egg\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 798, in __call__
pyasn1.error.PyAsn1Error: TagSet(Tag(tagClass=0, tagFormat=32, tagId=16)) not in asn1Spec: {TagSet(Tag(tagClass=0, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)): Integer()}/{}
```

My code:

```
pubkey = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(b"""-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBANkHLKYS2dByWQ3gKjQDvQbuWb/2Y9z4
eYuLEfgXdiP5qc5cG/5c+c/GgIl6yQY7AYeZVXiBXLaGzxiLZ5Y4fi0CAwEAAQ==
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----""", format='PEM')
crypto = rsa.encrypt("Secret", pubkey)
```

[Screen](http://kutj.es/22j-oj)
[RSA Documentations](http://stuvel.eu/files/python-rsa-doc/reference.html)

Comment: The RSA-Link does not work for me (403).

Comment: I can only say to try again, the link is working fine here.

Comment: [Try this](http://web.archive.org/web/20130603065836/http://stuvel.eu:80/files/python-rsa-doc/reference.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm doing right. But at least following encrypt without error.

```
import rsa
pubkey = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1_openssl_pem(b"""-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBANkHLKYS2dByWQ3gKjQDvQbuWb/2Y9z4
eYuLEfgXdiP5qc5cG/5c+c/GgIl6yQY7AYeZVXiBXLaGzxiLZ5Y4fi0CAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----""")
crypto = rsa.encrypt(b"Secret", pubkey)
```

NOTE: I changed `BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY` with `BEGIN PUBLIC KEY`. (same for `END RSA PUBLIC KEY`). And I used `load_pkcs1_openssl_pem`.

**UPDATE**

Pass a `bytes` object instead of `str` (especially if you are running this in Python 3.x).

Comment: Hmmm, the public key is successfully being read now (I think) but I'm recieving another error at the .encrypt() part. [Screen](http://kutj.es/7y1-ol)

Comment: @Anton, I didn't get any error. When I print `repr(crypto)`, I get: `'t\xc1]\xa8\x89\xac\xe9P\xd2(@\x96\xd8\xccL\xad[8\xc3\x17"\xc7\xe6\x7f~\xa8\x115K{\x0c\xe9u[o7\x80K.\xc6@\xb6w(\x9c\xac\xbb\xc5\xca\xec\nf\xfc\x9f\x00\xc3\xa09T\xcc\xf6Vy\x83'`

Comment: @Anton, Try replace `"Secret"` with its bytes string version: `b"Secret"`. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. I've needed to ask this before, so much time wasted

Comment: @Anton, I added `Python-3.x` tag because `bytes` object is not only related to Python-3.4, but for all Python-3.x.